# why does age of particle info node not work for Metaballs?

Tags: materials, particles

I can colorize my particles by age with an icosphere as object render in particle system.

[image]

If i use the same material setup for a metaball as object render ...it won't work. Age seems to be always 0. Is this a known bug or am i missing something?

[image]

Comment: It's probably because metaballs are something special. They are not like individuals, but  rather like mother  - the first metaballs object added into a scene, and others as children or helpers. If you hide first one all are gone. So there is a chance it would not work.